# Corona storyboard gives a black image

Tags: api, sdk, storyboard, coronasdk

I have created a menu with 2 buttons , and i am using storyboard API to move around scene , but it only works for the first button , for the other button it gives a black screen , I am positive there's nothing wrong in SCENE 2 , because i tried to set both scenes ( SCENE 1 and SCENE 2 ) the same code , and it worked with SCENE 1 but still gives a black image for SCENE 2 , here's my menu code , hopefully you can fix the error :

```
local storyboard = require ("storyboard")
local scene = storyboard.newScene()


   function scene:createScene(event)

local screenGroup = self.view

background = display.newImage("start.png")
background:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
background.x = 0
background.y = 320
background.speed = 1
screenGroup:insert(background)

city2 = display.newImage("city2.png")
city2:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
city2.x = 0
city2.y = 320
screenGroup:insert(city2)



play = display.newImage("play.png")
play.x = 242
play.y = 161
screenGroup:insert(play)

controls = display.newImage("controls.png")
controls.x = 144
controls.y = 201 
screenGroup:insert(controls)



function SCENE1(event)
if event.phase == "began" then
    storyboard.gotoScene("SCENE1", "fade", 400)
end
end

function SCENE2(event)
if event.phase == "began" then
    storyboard.gotoScene("SCENE2", "fade", 400)
end
end

function scene:enterScene(event)

 play:addEventListener("touch", SCENE1)
 controls:addEventListener("touch", SCENE2)
 end



function scene:exitScene(event)
play:removeEventListener("touch", SCENE1)
controls:removeEventListener("touch", SCENE2)
end

function scene:destroyScene(event)

end

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)

return scene
```

FOR SCENE 2 :

```
   module(..., package.seeall)

   -- requires 

   local physics = require "physics"
   physics.start()

   require "sprite"

   score = require ("score")

   local storyboard = require ("storyboard")
   local scene = storyboard.newScene()
  -- background

  function scene:createScene(event)

local screenGroup = self.view

background = display.newImage("bg.png")
screenGroup:insert(background)

scoreInfo = score.getInfo()
score.init({
x = 40,
y = 5}
)
score.setScore(0)

ceiling = display.newImage("invisibleTile.png")
ceiling:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
ceiling.x = 0
ceiling.y = 0
physics.addBody(ceiling, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2})
screenGroup:insert(ceiling)

theFloor = display.newImage("invisibleTile.png")
theFloor:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
theFloor.x = 0
theFloor.y = 340
physics.addBody(theFloor, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2})
screenGroup:insert(theFloor)


city1 = display.newImage("city1.png")
city1:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
city1.x = 0
city1.y = 320
city1.speed = 1
screenGroup:insert(city1)

city2 = display.newImage("city1.png")
city2:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
city2.x = 480
city2.y = 320
city2.speed = 1
screenGroup:insert(city2)

city3 = display.newImage("city2.png")
city3:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
city3.x = 0
city3.y = 320
city3.speed = 2
screenGroup:insert(city3)

city4 = display.newImage("city2.png")
city4:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
city4.x = 480
city4.y = 320
city4.speed = 2
screenGroup:insert(city4)


jetSpriteSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet("jet.png", 50, 17)
jetSprites = sprite.newSpriteSet(jetSpriteSheet, 1, 4)
sprite.add(jetSprites, "jets", 1, 4, 1000, 0)
jet = sprite.newSprite(jetSprites)
jet.x = -80
jet.y = 100
jet:prepare("jets")
jet:play()
jet.collided = false
physics.addBody(jet, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=12})
screenGroup:insert(jet)
jetIntro = transition.to(jet,{time=2000, x=100, onComplete=jetReady})

explosionSpriteSheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet("explosion.png", 24, 23)
explosionSprites = sprite.newSpriteSet(explosionSpriteSheet, 1, 8)
sprite.add(explosionSprites, "explosions", 1, 8, 2000, 1)
explosion = sprite.newSprite(explosionSprites)
explosion.x = 100
explosion.y = 100
explosion:prepare("explosions")
 -- explosion:play()
explosion.isVisible = false
-- physics.addBody(jet, "dynamic", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=12})
screenGroup:insert(explosion)

mine1 = display.newImage("mine.png")
mine1.x = math.random(480,500)
mine1.y = math.random(1,100)
mine1.speed = math.random(2,6)
mine1.initY = mine1.y
mine1.amp = math.random(20,90)
mine1.angle = math.random(1,360)
physics.addBody(mine1, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=12})
screenGroup:insert(mine1)

mine2 = display.newImage("mine.png")
mine2.x = math.random(900,950)
mine2.y = math.random(1,100)
mine2.speed = math.random(2,6)
mine2.initY = mine2.y
mine2.amp = math.random(20,100)
mine2.angle = math.random(1,360)
physics.addBody(mine2, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=12})
screenGroup:insert(mine2)


mine3 = display.newImage("mine.png")
mine3.x = math.random(1450,1570)
mine3.y = math.random(300,340)
mine3.speed = math.random(2,6)
mine3.initY = mine3.y
mine3.amp = math.random(20,70)
mine3.angle = math.random(1,360)
physics.addBody(mine3, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=12})
screenGroup:insert(mine3)

mine4 = display.newImage("mine.png")
mine4.x = math.random(2500,2770)
mine4.y = math.random(330,330)
mine4.speed = math.random(2,6)
mine4.initY = mine3.y
mine4.amp = math.random(20,100)
mine4.angle = math.random(1,360)
physics.addBody(mine4, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=12})
screenGroup:insert(mine4)

mine6 = display.newImage("mine.png")
mine6.x = math.random(4000,4770)
mine6.y = math.random(1,320)
mine6.speed = math.random(2,6)
mine6.initY = mine6.y
mine6.amp = math.random(20,80)
mine6.angle = math.random(1,360)
physics.addBody(mine6, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=12})
screenGroup:insert(mine6)

mine5 = display.newImage("mine.png")
mine5.x = math.random(5500,5770)
mine5.y = math.random(1,130)
mine5.speed = math.random(2,6)
mine5.initY = mine5.y
mine5.amp = math.random(20,80)
mine5.angle = math.random(1,360)
physics.addBody(mine5, "static", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2, radius=12})
screenGroup:insert(mine5)
end

 function scrollCity(self,event)
if self.x < -477 then
    self.x = 480
else 
    self.x = self.x - self.speed
end
 end

  function moveMines(self,event)
if self.x < -50 then
     self.x = 500
     self.y = math.random(90,220)
     self.speed = math.random(2,6)
     self.amp = math.random(20,100)
     self.angle = math.random(1,360)
else 
    self.x = self.x - self.speed
    self.angle = self.angle + .1
    self.y = self.amp*math.sin(self.angle)+self.initY
end
end

function addtoit (event)
if event.phase == "ended" then
score.setScore (score.getScore()+1)
end
end


function jetReady()
jet.bodyType = "dynamic"
end

function activateJets(self,event)
self:applyForce(0, -1.5, self.x, self.y)
print("run")
end

function touchScreen(event)
print("touch")
if event.phase == "began" then
 jet.enterFrame = activateJets
     Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", jet)
end

if event.phase == "ended" then
 Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", jet)
  end

end

function gameOver()
storyboard.gotoScene("restart", "fade", 400)
end

function explode()

explosion.x = jet.x
explosion.y = jet.y
explosion.isVisible = true
explosion:play()
jet.isVisible = false
timer.performWithDelay(3000, gameOver, 1)

end
 local taSound = audio.loadSound("GAME.mp3")
 local tapSound = audio.loadSound("explosion-01.wav")
function onCollision(event)
if event.phase == "began" then
  if jet.collided == false then 
    jet.collided = true
    jet.bodyType = "static"
    explode()
     audio.stop()
     audio.play(tapSound ,{ duration=3100 } )
     background:removeEventListener("touch", addtoit)
  end
end
end


 function scene:enterScene(event)


storyboard.purgeScene("start")
storyboard.purgeScene("restart")

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touchScreen)

city1.enterFrame = scrollCity
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", city1)

city2.enterFrame = scrollCity
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", city2)

city3.enterFrame = scrollCity
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", city3)

city4.enterFrame = scrollCity
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", city4)

mine1.enterFrame = moveMines
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", mine1)

mine2.enterFrame = moveMines
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", mine2)

mine3.enterFrame = moveMines
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", mine3)

mine4.enterFrame = moveMines
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", mine4)

mine5.enterFrame = moveMines
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", mine5)

 mine6.enterFrame = moveMines
 Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", mine6)

 Runtime:addEventListener("collision", onCollision)

audio.play(taSound)
 background:addEventListener("touch", addtoit)
end

function scene:exitScene(event)

Runtime:removeEventListener("touch", touchScreen)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", city1)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", city2)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", city3)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", city4)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", mine1)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", mine2)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", mine3)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", mine4)
Runtime:removeEventListener("collision", onCollision)

end

function scene:destroyScene(event)

end
scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)
return scene
```

Comment: can you provide the code for SCENE2 ?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in the `scene:enterScene` you try to load your city object over and over again at the same time there are so many runtime listener in your code that it repeats calling the same object.
are you creating a sidescrolling game? if so you can try to see this link on how to create side scrolling game from scratch http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/corona/corona-sdk-create-a-side-scroller-from-scratch/
hopes this helps